# How do I emit events from a child component to a parent component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a child component nested in a parent component. I want the parent component to get notified whenever an event takes place in a child component. In Vue, I could do this:

```
// inside the child component EventButton

// the event 'someEvent' gets emitted whenever the button is clicked
<button @click="$emit('someEvent')">
  Emit event
</button>
```

```
// inside the parent component

<EventButton @someEvent="() => do something" />
```

How can I achieve the same functionality in React?

Some clarification: I want an event to be emitted to the parent component whenever I like e.g., when an item has been added to a list, and not just when a button is clicked.

Comment: onClick={() => console.log("clicked")}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way you can achieve this is to give to the child component as props a function defined in the parent component.

In parent:

```
function notify_me(){
     #do what you want to do in the parent component using a state for example
}
```

At the child definition:

```
<Child notify_parent ={notify_me} />
```

In Child component:

```
<EventButton @someEvent={() => props.notify_parent()}/>
```